# Argument Exception when hit to print option

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
      private void printToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        printDialog1.AllowCurrentPage = true;
        printDialog1.AllowPrintToFile = true;
        printDialog1.AllowSelection = true;
        printDialog1.AllowSomePages = true;

       // pageSetupDialog1.PageSettings.Margins;
        printDialog1.PrinterSettings = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings();

         pageSetupDialog1.ShowDialog();
         DialogResult dk = pageSetupDialog1.ShowDialog();
         if (dk == DialogResult.OK)
         {
             object[] resul = new object[]{
                printDialog1.PrinterSettings.MaximumCopies,
                printDialog1.PrintToFile,
                printDialog1.ShowNetwork,

            };


        }
        .
```

hi, I am try my best and search in Google but not yet my problem is solve. i know on stackoverflow solve this error. i have in my  project control are  textbox,menustrip and openDialogbox,PrintDialog and so on.

Comment: why are you calling pageSetupDialog1.ShowDialog() twice?

Comment: sir i try delete one pagesetupDialog1. but error has still there...

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what the actual error/problem is that you are facing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A method can be called with invalid arguments. An ArgumentException may be thrown in this case. Exceptions use derived types to indicate their meaning, but this doesn't give them extra abilities. Semantically, ArgumentException indicates that a method was called with an invalid argument. 
for more Information :
[click here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/argumentexception)